# Android progess animation by dragging(not by time)

Tags: android

I know that animation can be progressed along time.

```
TranslateAnimation in = new TranslateAnimation(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
in.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(mContext,
                        android.R.anim.accelerate_interpolator));
in.setDuration(500);
```

But i want animation progress along certain value. For example, drag distance. How can i achieve this?

Comment: *But i want animation progress along certain value. For example, drag distance*, what does it mean ?

Comment: @Blackbelt usually animation progress along time. Fore example, if i set duration 2 seconds, 50% progress of the animation will be happen at 1 sec. I'd like to do this along drag distance. If i set maximum distance to 200px, 50% progress of the animation will be happen after i dragged 100px.